# What is this style called?

Tags: website-design, google-material-design, website-templates, minimalistic, bootstrap

This is a repost [from the ux stackexchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/123193/what-is-this-style-called).

I am trying to find the name of the style of the following websites. It's a mix of classic bootstrap and material design. But instead of full material design it offers more depth and just looks a lot nicer.

- https://vwo.com -> the dropdown cards and feeling of depth on this one are amazing
- https://balance.io/
- https://dev.status.im/
- https://makerdao.com/en/

I've seen more of this style lately and would like to know more about it. I really like the simple card style, especially the dropdown menu card on [this site](https://vwo.com/). There always seems to be some overlay of one element into another.

Comment: You should include images of the particular aspects you're taking about in the question itself so that your question will make sense if the sites change design

Comment: What Zach said. Also, why'd you repost it and not just migrate it?

Comment: @WELZ because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can flag for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it. Or you can just delete the one from there as this is already posted.

Comment: I'll add images later. Does anyone know what this style is called?

Comment: Add images (but not *too many*) = get better help.

Comment: I'm on linux so screenshots are a pain. Can't you just check the websites I linked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't  know that there's a specific "name" for the style merely based upon the usage as a menu pop up.

They are merely "**Modal Windows**" triggered by menus, nothing more. The same in-page popups could be triggered by anything. I don't think connecting them to menus gives them any more style specitivity.

The Makerdao link is nothing more than a CSS popup menu created with HTML lists and CSS, different, simpler, construction than the others. But theoretically you could use the same general markup to create the page-wide popup menu items as well.

---

Basically some are just CSS Popup Menus using HTML Lists and CSS, and some are Modal Windows.

Any sense of "depth" is created via the CSS `box-shadow` property or just visual styling, but I don't think there's a specific "name" for it.